# Why do shortened versions of long options work with getopt?

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

In the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
func_usage ()
{
cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                                                                  \
                                                                                                                                                                                            
USAGE: ${0}                                                                                                                                                                                \
                                                                                                                                                                                            
EOF                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
## Defining_Version                                                                                                                                                                         
version=1.0
## Defining_Input                                                                                                                                                                           
options=$(getopt -o "t:" -l "h,help,v,version,taxonomy:" -a -- "$@")
eval set -- "$options"
while true;do
    case $1 in
        -h|--h|-help|--help)
            func_usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        -v|--v|-version|--version)
            echo $version
            ;;
        -t|--t|-taxonomy|--taxonomy)
            echo "Option t = $2 ";
            Taxonomy_ID=$2
            echo $Taxonomy_ID
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break;;
    esac
    shift
done
## Defining Taxonomy Default Value (in case is not provided)
TaxonomyID=${Taxonomy_ID:=9606};
echo $TaxonomyID
exit 0
```

The commands:

```
./script.sh -v
./script.sh --v
./script.sh -version
./script.sh --version
```

Work as expected. But what I do not understand is why the commands:

```
./script.sh -ver
./script.sh --ver
```

work at all. An equivalent unexpected behavior is also observed for the commands:

```
./script.sh -tax 22
./script.sh --tax 22
```

I would be grateful to get an explanation and/or a way to correct this unexpected behavior.

Comment: try double quoting `"-v"|"--v"|"-version"|"--version"`

Comment: @SriniV, in the `case` statements? That would make no difference at all. You only need double quotes in a case when doing so disambiguates syntax that would otherwise be, well, ambiguous. `-v` only matches `-v`, even when unquoted. A case where you'd need quotes would be `"-*"`, if you want it to match only `-*` and not `-foo`

Comment: @RodolfoAramayo, when you want to see how something works in bash, that's what `set -x` is for. https://ideone.com/9gAPe9 shows it clearly: getopt is changing `-tax` to `--taxonomy`.

Comment: ...that said, `getopt` is generally considered a bad idea. [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) bans even discussion of it, pushing it out into the hinterlands of the [Complex Option Parsing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing) wiki page (which mostly describes frowned-on approaches and _why_ they're not good practice). I'd strongly suggest moving to one of the BashFAQ-recommended approaches instead.

Comment: To answer the question, it's documented to work that way: "Long options may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is not ambiguous." -- check your getopt(1) man page. If you also had the long option `taxation`, then providing `--tax 22` would issue an error:  "getopt: option '--tax' is ambiguous"

Comment: (btw, `getopt`'s behavior isn't part of bash, because getopt itself isn't part of bash; it's provided by your operating system, and it has two completely-incompatible sets of behavior between Linuxy systems and everywhere else; using it thus makes your scripts completely nonportable beyond Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Note that `getopt` is an external utility unrelated to Bash.

> what I do not understand is why the commands: .. work at all.

Because `getopt` was designed to support it, there is no other explanation. From `man getopt`:

> [...] Long options may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is not ambiguous.

Unambiguous abbreviations of long options are converted to long options.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I have received, specially from @CharlesDuffy, I have modified my code to what I believe is a more robust and compatible version. Importantly, the code below addresses the pitfalls of the original code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                         
func_usage ()
{
cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                                                                   
USAGE: ${0}                                                                                                                                                                                 
EOF
## Defining_Version                                                                                                                                                                         
version=1.0
## Defining_Input                                                                                                                                                                           
while true;do
    case $1 in
        -h|--h|-help|--help|-\?|--\?)
            func_usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        -v|--v|-version|--version)
            echo $version
            ;;
        -t|--t|-taxonomy|--taxonomy)
            echo "Option t = $2 ";
            Taxonomy_ID=$2
            echo $Taxonomy_ID
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break;;
        -?*)
            printf 'WARN: Unknown option (ignored): %s\n' "$1" >&2
            ;;
        *)
            break
    esac
    shift
done
TaxonomyID=${Taxonomy_ID:=9606};
echo $TaxonomyID
exit 0
```

The code above behaves as expected in that the commands:

```
./script -tax 22
```

Gives the warning:

```
WARN: Unknown option (ignored): -tax
9606
```

As expected